# mixing spring and jersy?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a web application that works great
and I would like to integrate it with another web application that is rest interface in JSON implemented using Jersey

the spring controllers are using RequestMapping like:

```
@Controller
public class AdminPrinterController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/contact/view.action")
public @ResponseBody
Map<String, ? extends Object> view() throws Exception {...}
```

while the Jersey controllers look like?:

```
 @Path("/printerList")
 public class PrinterListApi{

@Path("/internalPrinterList/{locationId}")
```

I integrated the code, but its obviously not working... probably because spring is intercepting the Jersey URL

this is my spring filter mapping:

```
    <filter-mapping>  
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>  
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
    </filter-mapping>
```

Can Jersey live together with spring?
Or should i switch to Spring rest implementation
Thank you

Comment: Both frameworks are build on top of Servlet API and both are backed by a Servlet at the very base. If the URLs of your resources in Jersey and Spring do not overlap, you can make them live side by side.

Comment: Why it's not working? What is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible.  You'll have to include the spring-jersey dependency in your project. Then you should be able to use the standard spring servlet mapping.  I pulled this out of a pretty old project so you might want to check for updated  versions. Mixing jersey and spring is a little messy though.  I think the more modern way is to follow a spring boot rest tutorial.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <!-- if your container implements Servlet API older than 3.0, use "jersey-container-servlet-core" -->
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.23</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
            <version>2.23</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>bean-validator</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Sorry for the edit. I forgot in your web.xml you'll have to point to the jersey servlet container.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SpringApplication</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.application.MainApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SpringApplication</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```